# Plot feasible region of a high-dimensional LP only along some dimensions

Tags: plotting, mathematical-optimization, linear-algebra

I have a question on the possibility of using Mathematica to plot a convex closed region satisfying a linear system of equalities and inequalities.

Let me first present the linear system. Let $x\equiv (x_1,...,x_{34})$ be a $34\times 1$ vector of unknowns. Let $A,C,E,b,d$ be matrices of known parameters with appropriate dimensions. The linear system is

$
1) A\times (x_1,...,x_{32})=b$     ,

$
2)C\times(x_1,...,x_{32}) \leq d$,

$
3)E\times(x_1,...,x_{32})-(x_{33},x_{34})=0$,

The matrices are here https://filebin.net/e7k3749uxd2f1dg4, in `.mat` format. They are too big to be reported.

**My objective:** I would like to plot the region of values of $(x_{33},x_{34})$ for which there exists $(x_1,...,x_{32})$ such that $(x_1,...,x_{34})$ satisfies $1),2),3)$.

**Question:** Can Mathematica allow me to plot the desired $2$-D region? The tricky part here is to explore the set of solution of $1),2)$ with respect to $(x_1,...,x_{32})$. I typically use Matlab which, however, to the best of my knowledge, does not have packages doing what I want due to the high dimension of the problem.

**Clarification**: I have never used Mathematica (hence, I don't have a code of attempts to show you), but I'd be happy to start studying it if you tell me that it can help me with my question.

**Clarification 2**:  there exists at least one value of $(x_1,...,x_{34})$ satisfying 1),2),3). It is here https://filebin.net/e7k3749uxd2f1dg4 under the name `possible_solution_complete.mat`.

Comment: I think you can just use Reduce, but it's hard to say without knowing what the parameters are.

Comment: A good start would be to provide the set matrices and constraints.  Also, please include code of what you have tried and what is not working for you.

Comment: Question updated in directions to your comments.

Comment: Your `e` matrix has dimensions $2 \times 34$ and you're multiplying by a vector of length 32. You should fix that.

Comment: It is fixed now and the region contains at least one solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read the matrices:

```
a = Import["A.mat"][[1]] // Round;
c = Import["C.mat"][[1]] // Round;
e = Import["E.mat"][[1]];
b = Import["b.mat"] // Flatten;
d = Import["d.mat"] // Flatten // Round;
```

construct the system of equalities and inequalities:

```
X = Array[x, 34];
S = Join[Thread[a.X[[;; 32]] == b],
         Thread[c.X[[;; 32]] <= d], 
         Thread[e.X[[;; 32]] - {X[[33]], X[[34]]} == 0]];
```

Experimental mathematics: find 100 random instances that satisfy `S`:

```
j = FindInstance[S, X, Reals, 10^2];
```

For each instance, plot $(x_{33},x_{34})$:

```
J = X[[-2 ;;]] /. j;
ListPlot[J, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Notice that these points lie on the line $x_{33}+x_{34}=1$:

```
MinMax[Total /@ J]
(*    {0.9999999999999998, 1.0000000000000002}    *)
```

Find the vertices in the $x_{33}-x_{34}$ plane by minimizing/maximizing these parameters under the constraints:

```
P1 = X /. Minimize[{x[33], S}, X][[2]]
(*    {0., 0.304716, 0., 0.044609, 0., 0.544515, 0., 0.10616, 0.304716,
       0., 0.044609, 0., 0., 0.544515, 0.10616, 0., 0., 0.304716, 0.,
       0.044609, 0., 0.544515, 0., 0.10616, 0., 0.304716, 0., 0.044609,
       0., 0.544515, 0., 0.10616, 0.0505921, 0.949408}    *)

P2 = X /. Maximize[{x[33], S}, X][[2]]
(*    {0.304716, 0., 0.044609, 0., 0.044609, 0.499906, 0.10616, 0.,
       0.304716, 0., 0.044609, 0., 0.544515, 0., 0.10616, 0., 0.,
       0.304716, 0.044609, 0., 0., 0.544515, 0., 0.10616, 0.304716, 0.,
       0.044609, 0., 0.044609, 0.499906, 0.10616, 0., 0.415966, 0.584034}    *)

P3 = X /. Minimize[{x[34], S}, X][[2]]
(*    {0.304716, 0., 0.044609, 0., 0.044609, 0.499906, 0.10616, 0.,
       0.304716, 0., 0.044609, 0., 0.544515, 0., 0.10616, 0., 0.,
       0.304716, 0.044609, 0., 0., 0.544515, 0., 0.10616, 0.304716, 0.,
       0.044609, 0., 0.044609, 0.499906, 0.10616, 0., 0.415966, 0.584034}    *)

P4 = X /. Maximize[{x[34], S}, X][[2]]
(*    {0., 0.304716, 0., 0.044609, 0., 0.544515, 0., 0.10616, 0.304716,
       0., 0.044609, 0., 0., 0.544515, 0.10616, 0., 0., 0.304716, 0.,
       0.044609, 0., 0.544515, 0., 0.10616, 0., 0.304716, 0., 0.044609,
       0., 0.544515, 0., 0.10616, 0.0505921, 0.949408}    *)
```

There are actually only two inequivalent points:

```
P1 == P4
(*    True    *)

P2 == P3
(*    True    *)
```

Therefore, the domain you're looking for is the line from `P1` to `P2`, projected onto the $x_{33}-x_{34}$ plane:

```
{P1[[-2 ;;]], P2[[-2 ;;]]}
(*    {{0.0505921, 0.949408}, {0.415966, 0.584034}}    *)
```

You can plot the domain (in general) with

```
ConvexHullMesh[{P1, P2, P3, P4}[[All, -2 ;;]], Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {x33, x34}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'm sorry but I did a mistake when building the matrices! I had to convert them from Matlab format and this confused me! They are fixed now and  the program has at least one solution.

Comment: Can you tell us what that one known solution is? Because I just tried with your new coefficients and still don't get any solutions.

Comment: I have uploaded it under the same link. I know little of Mathematica coding but I think that maybe  `Thread[e.X == 0]` does not correspond to $E\times (x_1,...,x_{32})-(x_{33},x_{34})=0$.

Comment: Yes I had modified it to `Thread[e.X[[;; 32]] - {X[[33]], X[[34]]} == 0]` before trying; still no luck. But you're right that your solution seems to work.

Comment: I understood the problem I think: the .txt extension was producing wrong numbers (I haven't got yet why). Now, the files are in the .mat extension and should work fine.